# Spring MVC - Unable to load images in controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

**UPDATE:**

I got it to work by using ClassPathResource as M. Deinum had suggested.
I've also removed my WebMvcConfig, I'm not sure if that is related to the problem though.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage() throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("static/images/user-default.png");
        InputStream in = classPathResource.getInputStream();
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
```

---

I'm working on a Spring Boot project with Spring MVC architecture and Spring Security. I can't pinpoint where I mis-configured my MVC configurations, I have a problem where my **controller** is unable to find the image I specified.

Here's my controller which serves images:

```java
@Controller
public class ImageController {
    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/images/user-default.png");
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
}
```

Through debugging I found that the **InputStream** resulted in **null**. However, I'm actually **able** to load the image on my browser through a **Thymeleaf template**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<!--omitted for brevity-->
<img th:src="@{/images/quiz-academic.png}"/> <!--This WORKS, image is VISIBLE in the browser-->
<!--omitted for brevity-->
</html>
```

Or by accessing it with a **direct path**:

```html
http://localhost:8080/images/user-default.png (This WORKS, image is VISIBLE in the browser)
```

I'm confused as to why my **controller** is not able to pick up the image yet the two above methods **(Thymeleaf, direct path)** could do that without any problem.

Here's my MVC Configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/images/");
    }
}
```

Here's my Security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error");
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/user").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/image").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
                /* login/logout configuration omitted for brevity */
    }
}
```

And my project directories:

```
src/main/java/com/kjnts/springwebapp/config/WebSecurityConfig.java
src/main/java/com/kjnts/springwebapp/config/WebMvcConfig.java
src/main/java/com/kjnts/springwebapp/controller/ImageController.java
src/main/resources/static/images/user-default.png
src/main/resources/templates/user-profile.html
```

If you are wondering, I don't use XML for Spring configuration.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Remove that image endpiint, 2. remove your `WebMvcConfig` (that actually disables auto-configuration). If you really need that controller don't use the `ServletContext` to load the file (as that will try to load it from `/WEB-INF` not the classpath. Instead use a `ClasspathResource` from spring as it needs to come from the classpath.

Comment: Thank you. I've got it to work correctly with ClassPathResource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I should post an answer so I could mark it as answered.

---

I got it to work by using ClassPathResource as M. Deinum had suggested.
I've also removed my WebMvcConfig, I'm not sure if that is related to the problem though.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage() throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("static/images/user-default.png");
        InputStream in = classPathResource.getInputStream();
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
```